# Is it possible to set Highcharts to hide tooltip when the mouse pointer is 30px away

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Based on http://www.highcharts.com/demo/synchronized-charts, I want to hide the tooltips (the x value at the top right) when the focus is out of the chart.

Is it possible to show the tooltip when it's close to the point rather than showing it on every `mousemove`?

I want this behavior because I have gaps (missing data points). For example, one chart has values from 0 to 500 and from 600 to 800 another from 300 to 800.  So, when the use hover on second chart around 550 it's showing 500 on the first chart.  This is misleading for the user.

```js
/*
The purpose of this demo is to demonstrate how multiple charts on the same page can be linked
through DOM and Highcharts events and API methods. It takes a standard Highcharts config with a
small variation for each data set, and a mouse/touch event handler to bind the charts together.
*/

$(function () {

    /**
     * In order to synchronize tooltips and crosshairs, override the
     * built-in events with handlers defined on the parent element.
     */
    $('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
        var chart,
            point,
            i,
            event;

        for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
            chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
            event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart
        event.chartX = (event.chartX+600) % 200;
            point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point

            if (point !== undefined && point.distX < 20 && point.dist < 20) {
                point.highlight(e);
            }
        }
    });
    /**
     * Override the reset function, we don't need to hide the tooltips and crosshairs.
     */
    Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
        return undefined;
    };

    /**
     * Highlight a point by showing tooltip, setting hover state and draw crosshair
     */
    Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function (event) {
        this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
        this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip
        this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
    };

    /**
     * Synchronize zooming through the setExtremes event handler.
     */
    function syncExtremes(e) {
        var thisChart = this.chart;

        if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
            Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (chart) {
                if (chart !== thisChart) {
                    if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
                        chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, undefined, false, { trigger: 'syncExtremes' });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    // Get the data. The contents of the data file can be viewed at
    // https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/activity.json
    $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=activity.json&callback=?', function (activity) {
        $.each(activity.datasets, function (i, dataset) {

            // Add X values
            dataset.data = Highcharts.map(dataset.data, function (val, j) {
                return [activity.xData[j], val];
            });

            $('<div class="chart" style="width:200px;float:left;">')
                .appendTo('#container')
                .highcharts({
                    chart: {
                        marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
                        spacingTop: 20,
                        spacingBottom: 20
                    },
                    title: {
                        text: dataset.name,
                        align: 'left',
                        margin: 0,
                        x: 30
                    },
                    credits: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    legend: {
                        enabled: false
                    },
                    xAxis: {
                        crosshair: true,
                        events: {
                            setExtremes: syncExtremes
                        },
                        labels: {
                            format: '{value} km'
                        }
                    },
                    yAxis: {
                        title: {
                            text: null
                        }
                    },
                    tooltip: {
                        positioner: function () {
                            return {
                                x: this.chart.chartWidth - this.label.width, // right aligned
                                y: -1 // align to title
                            };
                        },
                        borderWidth: 0,
                        backgroundColor: 'none',
                        pointFormat: '{point.y}',
                        headerFormat: '',
                        shadow: false,
                        style: {
                            fontSize: '18px'
                        },
                        valueDecimals: dataset.valueDecimals
                    },
                    series: [{
                        data: dataset.data,
                        name: dataset.name,
                        type: dataset.type,
                        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
                        fillOpacity: 0.3,
                        tooltip: {
                            valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
                        }
                    }]
                });
        });
    });
});
```

```css
.chart {
    
}
</style>
<!-- http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/hacks.html#css-panel-hack -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: You can disable [stickyTracking](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.stickyTracking) param. If problem will still appear, please update jsifddle with your data.

Comment: I will check and let you know.. Thanks for the tip.. :)

Comment: I will update the fiddle with new data.. which I use

Comment: It does not work, only thing I need is need to show the tooltip when the mouse is close to the point else it should hide.

Comment: Meanwhile I am trying to get the sample data

Comment: What type of series do you use? Line or other ?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for helping.. :)  I am using scatter now,  now I kind of found a crooked solution..  I will updated once it is fully working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, however this might not be the correct way,  however I feel this may help to get temporary solution.

I replaced the

```
if (point)
```

With

```
if (point !== undefined && point.distX < 20 && point.dist < 20) {
```

I added extra check to distX and dist are less than 20 (We can adjust the values as we like)

Updated my fiddle on the question,

Now facing different issue, when the cursor is away I need to hide the marker as well.  Looking in to it.